# Error with nlapiYieldScript from a Scheduled Script (SS1.0)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

IN SuiteScript 1.0, I'm getting NLAPIYIELDSCRIPT_MUST_BE_CALLED_FROM_A_SCHEDULED_SCRIPT even though the script is scheduled.

The pathway to execution:

1. Custom Suitelet Form with a custom button
2. Custom button triggers a client script
3. Client Script triggers a SuiteLet as administrator

   `var sletURL = nlapiResolveURL('SUITELET', 'customscriptjcse_au_da_manual_paymentupd', 'customdeployjcse_au_da_manual_paymentupd',false)+'&userid='+currentUser;
   var resp = nlapiRequestURL(sletURL);`
4. Suitelet triggers script:

   `var result = nlapiScheduleScript('customscriptjcse_au_da_payment_ss', 'customdeployjcse_au_da_payment_ss_manual', params);`

Even the logging of the scheduled script context says:

`Started at: 20:28:50 GMT-0800 (PST) by User ID: 7880 Context: scheduled`

Wihtin the scheduled script, i have:

`if (context.getRemainingUsage() < 250 ) {
   nlapiYieldScript();
 }
context.setPercentComplete((processed/trancount*100).toFixed(1));`

Any ideas why this error is coming up??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your scheduled script logic, for use of every, filter, forEach, map and some. SuiteScript cannot yield in the middle of these control structures. That was my case in the forEach I was tried to nlapiYieldScript() and the SuiteScript throwed NLAPIYIELDSCRIPT_MUST_BE_CALLED_FROM_A_SCHEDULED_SCRIPT.

[image]